# real time notification with spring boot and react js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

i am new to spring boot please any one can help me. for an example notification table new data insert into table our back end sever listen and at the same time particular client get notification real time so this scenario how to implement spring boot and react js.

Comment: search for websocket and suckjs in spring boot

Comment: Can you please add some code that you've tried?

Comment: use sse to send notification to subscriber . here is the detail https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events